# Android: Download an image from the server

Tags: android

I'm writing a custom lock screen app that would show a random chess puzzle (as an image) on the lock screen. I have the puzzles stored on my server and I also have the basic lock screen written which is currently showing a default fallback image.

Now I want to replace the lock screen image every day at noon GMT by downloading the puzzle of the day from the server. So that when the user tries to unlock the phone anytime after noon, he sees the latest puzzle for the next 24 hours.

What is the best way to implement this downloading scenario?

Answer (score 0):

here is the guide to download data from network :

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#download

here is how to set repeating alarm to trigger your download :

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html